# Defenses have disappeared in a settlement

Tags: fallout-4

I have disappearing turrets. This is when I am actually at the settlement looking at the spot where turrets used to be--**this is not the issue with the pip-boy displaying incorrect stats**.

For instance there is a settlement where I had 10 missile turrets strung together. The turrets are gone but the wires are there, connected to, well, nothing, and the defense rating is down to 5.

I thought it might be just one buggy settlement, but I've found another settlement with a missing turret.

Anyone else experiencing this or have any suggestions on how to fix, aside from rebuilding all the defenses?

Comment: Tried looking around, are they *anywhere*? Could be a problem with them being placed when the scene renders. Just a theory.

Comment: @Iszi I looked around...left the settlements and went back a couple times thinking the game may sort it out, but they're just missing. Weirdest thing...

Comment: @Corinne I went back a few saves and found one where everything was intact (defense back up to 474). It looks like all I lost progress-wise was unlocking a settlement and building it and another out. Sucks, but better than rebuilding all those turrets.

Comment: Try this, it seemed to help for me. Get to somewhere ridiculously far away from the settlement. Far enough that the cell is not loaded. Then, walk back. Or, fast travel to a place, that is not the settlement, but close, and walk the rest of the way. For example, if the problem is in Sanctuary Hills, travel to say, Tenpines Bluff, or Super Duper Mart. Then, Fast travel to Red Rocket, and walk to Sanctuary.

Comment: Are you playing on PC with any mods? I had a couple mods running that gave minor cheats such as carry capacity increase and ever since the first major patch, I've had issues with most of the mods I got from Nexus Mods.

Comment: Is it possible that the settlement was attacked and some of the defenses were destroyed?

Comment: I came across something, somewhere, that mentions there might be a hard limit to the number of turrets you can have in-game at any one time. Did you build more turrets elsewhere and then return?

Comment: @sworcery - nope, I'm on the xbox. >Tim, nope, there were too many missing for it to be an attack, and I've never had one go missing after attack, I've only seen them in need of repair. >Mazura, I've built tons since this issue, and haven't encountered the problem again--I think it was just a weird glitch.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is just a random bug that has no definitive cause or fix aside from reloading a previous save. I was able to find [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutsettlements/comments/3xpjvv/new_bug_to_be_aware_of_my_settlement_just_had_all/) and [this thread](http://www.gamesas.com/normal-settlement-bug-now-defense-disappears-t401027.html) that described issues similar to yours.

Unfortunately, it looks like at this time, the only way to fix this is to reload a previous save when it happens while you wait for a patch, as I haven't found any evidence that one has been released to fix this yet.